# WPF DoubleUpDown command binding to up down buttons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ScalingFactor, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=F5}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" behaviors:TextBoxBehavior.SelectAllTextOnFocus="True" behaviors:InputBindingsManager.SourceProperty="TextBox.Text"/>
  <Button  Command="{Binding MultiplyCommand}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           Margin="{StaticResource MarginItemLeft}">
           <Image Source="/Themes;component/BaseTheme/Images/Add.png" Stretch="None" />
  </Button>
  <Button  Command="{Binding DivideCommand}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         Margin="{StaticResource MarginItemLeft}">
          <Image Source="/Themes;component/BaseTheme/Images/Minus.png" Stretch="None" />
  </Button>
```

I have a text box with two commands,
Since this really looks like DoubleUpDown from WPF extended tools kit I thought of replacing all of this code with it.
However I can't find any documentation of how to bind the commands?
Can you help me connecting multiplyCommand into the up key and DivideCommand into the down key?

Comment: You need to create a custom control derived from TextBox, then you can modify the ControlTemplate of the control. In the control template add the buttons for Up and Down. In the custom control you can handle the key up and key down event which can be exposed as commands.

Comment: @Ganesh I don't want to inherit TextBox, I want to use WPF extended tool kit. not creating a custom control

Comment: Could you please provide more info about what exactly you are trying to do? I am having a hard time understanding the question. Do you want to replace the template of the WPF double up down with this template?

Comment: @h.alex I want to replace my TextBox+2 buttons with DoubleUpDown control. However i want to maintain my logic, which means when i hit the up button in the DoubleUpDown MultiplyCommand is being called and same for down button and DivideCommand

Comment: Ok, the simplest thing - if at all possible - can you monitor your VM for ScalingFactor value changed event, and call your commands from there? I'll think about this further..

Comment: Or - you can try [attaching a command property](http://www.codeproblem.com/articles/frameworks/wpf/87-event-to-command-binding-using-attached-properties-in-plain-wpf-without-any-extra-dependancy). From the example - inside 'OnCalendarOpen' you dig-up each of the buttons from the UpDowns visual tree, and sign up for the click events (have one attached property for each of your commands). I think it's impossible to set the commands to the existing buttons, because they might already have commands set - to replace them could potentially break the functionality of the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to wrap the xaml you presented in a user /custom control (depending on the level of customization you need to allow) and then add dependency properties for the Min, Max and Value (to allow binding when used).On the Execute method of the up and down commands simply validate the expected value against the min and max.

Comment: I don't see how this replaces the existing xaml with the WPF Toolkit UpDown control..